# how do I use pyplot to display data when a breakpoint is hit in LLDB

Tags: python, lldb

I successfully can run a python script when a breakpoint is hit. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721980/lldb-python-handle-breakpoint-hit) I make a python module implementing my function with this signature:

```
breakpoint_function (frame, bp_loc, dict)
```

then I bring the module into lldb by doing:

```
(lldb) command script import "path to my .py file"
```

then I make a breakpoint and add my function to it like this:

```
(lldb) br com a -F MyModule.breakpoint_function
```

my module looks like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                                                                
import numpy as np  


def bp(frame, bp_loc, dict):

    a       = frame.FindVariable ("myFloatArray")

    for i in range(128):
        x[i]=  float(a.GetChildAtIndex(i,1,1).GetValue())


    # plt.ion()
    # plt.show()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.show()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    #plt.pause(10.001)


return 0
```

using just plt.plot(x) and plt.show() causes lldbdb to crash with the begining of the error log looking like this:

> 2016-12-22 21:26:51.192 lldb[32192:2025199] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1256.1/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:359
>   2016-12-22 21:26:51.192 lldb[32192:2025199] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
>   2016-12-22 21:26:51.272 lldb[32192:2025199] (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8da54ae2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90f7173c objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8da548ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9145c88c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
>       4   Foundation                          0x00007fff913e24c1 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 170
>       5   AppKit                              0x00007fff9bfd306a -[NSApplication run] + 844
>       6   _macosx.so                          0x00000001256c931e init_macosx + 32153
>       7   Python                              0x000000010e75aa90 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13533
>       8   Python                              0x000000010e7573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
>       9   Python                              0x000000010e75d4ae _PyEval_SliceIndex + 342
>       10  Python                              0x000000010e75a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609

When I call plt.ion() before plt.plot(x) first then nothing displays and i can continue stepping through lldb. Then when I quit lldb the plots actually show for a split second.

I tried changing backend in matplotlibrc with no luck
Also tried plt.show(block = True) (cause crashe with error log) 
Any hint would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get plt.show() to work either (in a lldb breakpoint). But the following workaround works for me and displays matplotlib images in a lldb breakpoint (with Xcode 7, lldb-340.4.70):

```
def bp1(frame, bp_loc, dict):
    """Use matplotlib in an Xcode breakpoint. 
    Add with: br com add -F cmd.bp1
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, sys
    # The following addition to the path may not be required in your case
    sys.path.append("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
    from PIL import Image

    print ("hit bp1")
    # Some example plot (sine curve)
    fig = plt.figure()
    Fs = 8000
    f = 5
    sample = 8000
    x = np.arange(sample)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
    fig.gca().plot(x, y)

    # Save figure to image
    fileName = "/Users/<username>/tempwork/lldb_pic.png"
    fig.savefig(fileName)

    # Open image from filesystem and show with PIL
    img = Image.open(fileName)
    img.show()
    return True  # False = continue execution, True = stop execution in debugger (lldb prompt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround which lets you use pylab's UI; it creates a new process. e.g. "plot x/2048fw buffer"

```
import lldb
import subprocess
import re
import io

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f plot.plot plot')

def plot(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    res = lldb.SBCommandReturnObject()
    interpreter = lldb.debugger.GetCommandInterpreter()
    interpreter.HandleCommand(command, res)
    if not res.Succeeded():
        print(res.GetError())
        return
    output = res.GetOutput()

    lines = output.splitlines()
    lines = '\n'.join(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'^.*: ', '', x), lines))

    cmd="""
import sys;
import pylab
import numpy
data = numpy.loadtxt(sys.stdin, dtype=numpy.float)
pylab.figure()
pylab.title("Plot")
pylab.plot(data)
pylab.xlim(0, data.size)
pylab.show()
"""

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", cmd], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    try:
        proc.communicate(lines, timeout=1)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        return
```